# Elasticsearch _timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I tried to define the `_timestamp` property on an index. 
So first, I create the index

`curl -XPUT 'http://elasticsearch:9200/ppe/'`

response from the server : `{"ok":true,"acknowledged":true}`

then I tried to define the mapping with a `_timestamp`

```
curl -Xput 'http://elasticsearch:9200/ppe/log/_mapping' -d '{
  "log": {
    "properties": {
      "_ttl": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "_timestamp": {
        "enabled": true,
        "store": "yes"
      },
      "message": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes"
      },
      "appid": {
        "type": "string",
        "store": "yes"
      },
      "level": {
        "type": "integer",
        "store": "yes"
      },
      "logdate": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "date_time_no_millis",
        "store": "yes"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

and I receive as answer from the server

```
{
  "error": "MapperParsingException[No type specified for property [_timestamp]]",
  "status": 400
}
```

What's wrong with my mapping?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Special fields such as `_ttl` and `_timestamp` have to be defined on the same level as the `properties` object:

```
curl -Xput 'http://elasticsearch:9200/ppe/log/_mapping' -d '{
    "log": {
        "_ttl": {
            "enabled": true
        },
        "_timestamp": {
            "enabled": true,
            "store": "yes"
        },
        "properties": {
            "message": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes"
            },
            "appid": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": "yes"
            },
            "level": {
                "type": "integer",
                "store": "yes"
            },
            "logdate": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "date_time_no_millis",
                "store": "yes"
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Answer (score 3):

Note though that although `_timestamp` is defined on top level it will be returned inside `fields`:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/AUqL0PW7YDMmKSIKO1bk?pretty=true&fields=_timestamp'
{
  "_index" : "myindex",
  "_type" : "mytype",
  "_id" : "AUqL0PW7YDMmKSIKO1bk",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "fields" : {
    "_timestamp" : 1419684935099
  }
}
```

Note that `_timestamp` must be explicitly requested by `fields=_timestamp` or `fields=_timestamp,_source`.

Note that `_timestamp` can be returned only when this field is marked as `'store': true`. But there is a way to access this value when sorting by `_timestamp`, like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search?pretty=true' -d ' 
   { "sort": [ "_timestamp" ], "size": 1}
 '
```

Gives result:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ {
       "_index" : "myindex",
       "_type" : "mytype",
       "_id" : "AUqL0PDXYDMmKSIKO1bj",
       "_score" : null,
       "sort" : [ 1419684933847 ]
     } ]
  }
}
```

And now `sort[0]` is the value for the first (and the only in this case) sort value: `_timestamp`. `_timestamp` does not have to be marked as `"store": true` when used in this manner.

Comment: I thought for a long time that my `_timestamp` settings on the index was incorrect or something because my documents weren't coming back with this field. Thank you for making the note "Note that '_timestamp' must be explicitly requested by 'fields=_timestamp' or 'fields=_timestamp,_source'.", this really helped me!