# How to enable logging when ElasticSearch indexes a record?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to measure the latency involved with using the ELK stack. I am logging in my test application and I want to find out how long it takes before it appears in ElasticSearch. I understand this will only be a rough estimate and is very specific to my environment.

How can I measure the latency between my app/logstash/elasticsearch?

EDIT: 
I am following [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867252/740839) and enabled _timestamp but I don't see the field in my records.

```
{
 logaggr : {
    order : 0,
    template : "logaggr-*",
    settings : {},
    mappings : {
        logaggr : {
            date_detection : false,
            _timestamp : {
                enabled : true,
                store: true
            },
            properties : {
                level : {
                    type : "string"
                },
                details : {
                    type : "string"
                },
                logts : {
                    format : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS",
                    type : "date"
                },
                classname : {
                    type : "string"
                },
                thread : {
                    type : "string"
                }                   
            }
        }
    },
    aliases : {}
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three timestamps that will answer your question:

1. the log file timestamp, e.g. when the application wrote the information.  Make sure your server's clock is correct.
2. @timestamp, which is set by logstash to the time when it receives the log.
3. _timestamp, which elasticsearch can set to the time when it receives the log.  [This setting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) must be enabled in elasticsearch.

Between these three, you can track the progress of your logs through ELK.

Comment: This should help me answer my question except I can't seem to get the _timestamp populated. I enabled _timestamp in my mapping and also set "store": true for this property but I don't see it when I query by ID Is there an additional flag to access it as well?

Comment: You may have to add it explicitly to your field list.

Comment: I am not able to get _timestamp populated even though my template shows  that _timestamp is enabled. I have edited my post to show the template. Any ideas?

Comment: Your mapping creates the field and indexes it (so you can search on it), but only "stored" fields are returned in queries.  One more mapping update!

Comment: Still could not see _timestamp even after I added "store": true. Until I realized from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744233/elasticsearch-timestamp post that the _timestamp must be at the same level as properties. Updated my post to show the template that works for me now. I can see _timestamp !!